# ANSIBLE: How to append variable from inventory groups

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have an ansible inventory with groups as follows:

```
  +hosts/
  +all/
  +group_vars/
    - linux.yml
    - webserver.yml
    - dbserver.yml
...
```

And I have a playbook that sets monitoring for hosts; and the kind of monitoring is done by plugins. So in each group y set a list `monitoring_plugins` that contain the plugin to be able t monitor each service.
  Inside each group yml I try to "append" to the list:

```
monitoring_plugins: {{ monitoring_plugins|default([]) + [ 'whatever_plugin_correspond_to_group' ] }}
```

But it doesn't work as expected, being expected that if a host belongs to more than one group, it should have the plugins corresponding to those groups.

Is there a way to acommplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're describing should work as expected **from within a task**, but you cannot have executable code in a `vars` or `group_vars` yaml or json file -- those are static

So you will need to set a distinct name at the low level and then roll them up at the top level:

```
group_vars/
  dbserver.yml  # sets monitoring_plugins_dbserver: ["a", "b"]
  linux.yml     # sets monitoring_plugins_linux: ["c", "d"]
```

and then in your tasks, something like this (but be forewarned I haven't tested *this specific example*):

```yaml
- set_fact:
    monitoring_plugins: >-
      {%- set results = [] -%}
      {%- for g in groups.keys() -%}
      {%- set _ = results.extend(vars['monitoring_plugins_' + g] | d([])) -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
      {{ results }}
```

Comment: wow, beautiful example, thanks for sharing it. What's the underscore variable (`set _ = ...`)?

Comment: Underscore is just like any other variable, you can also use any other variable name also, but in generally operations like this where value of variable dose not matter, mostly underscore is used as variable name.

Comment: Really elegant solution. I am going to vote it as correct but I think ansible should solve this without the need to add a task on every playbook/role to accumulate variables. Thanks!

Comment: I've used this with a couple of modifications to make it work, submitted as a suggested edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/35293149
This fixes it outputting a string with a lot of prefixed whitespace instead of a list.