# Merge variables into one

Tags: ansible

I have a problem with variable concatenation.
I have a main variable file named `all.yml`, I have 3 variables :

```
srvstatus_services_to_monitor_base:
  - sshd.service
  - vector.service
srvstatus_services_to_monitor_extra: []
srvstatus_services_to_monitor: "{{ srvstatus_services_to_monitor_base + srvstatus_services_to_monitor_extra }}"
```

`srvstatus_services_to_monitor_extra` is optional and should be overloaded in group_vars files. For example, with my docker group, I have a docker.yml file with this variable :

```
srvstatus_services_to_monitor_extra:
  - docker.service
```

When I display the value of srvstatus_services_to_monitor, my result is correct :

```
ansible server -m debug -a "var=srvstatus_services_to_monitor"
| SUCCESS => {
    "srvstatus_services_to_monitor": [
        "sshd.service",
        "vector.service",
        "docker.service"
    ]
```

But if I set `srvstatus_services_to_monitor_extra` in another group e.g nfs.yml with this content :

```
srvstatus_services_to_monitor_extra:
 - nfs.service
```

The content of the variable is not merged, I have just the information from nfs.yml not the concatenation of docker.yml and nfs.yml.

How I can merge the content of the same variable if she's defined more than once ?
Is is possible to do this in the variable file ?

My inventory is simple :

```
.
└── inventory
    ├── group_vars
    │   ├── all.yml
    │   ├── docker.yml
    │   └── nfs.yml
    └── hosts.ini
```

Content of hosts.ini file is also simple :

```
[docker]
server
[nfs]
server
```

Thanks for your help and advices.

[edit : elegant solution has been found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61319298/ansible-how-to-append-variable-from-inventory-groups)

Comment: Please add your [redacted] inventory to your question, so that it's clear what the structure is and where do the variables come from.

Comment: Hi, I have added my inventory in the original post

Comment: Thanks @Lud, bit could you also add the contents of `hosts.ini`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that *play vars* (precedence 12.) override *group_vars* (precedence 4.-7.). See [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence). You have to remove the below declaration of the empty list *extra* from the play

```yaml
  base: [sshd, vector]
  extra: []
  mon: "{{ base + extra }}"
```

But, this will make the play crash when the variable *extra* is not defined. To solve this problem, use the filter *default*

```yaml
  base: [sshd, vector]
  mon: "{{ base + extra|d([]) }}"
```

---

Example of a complete project for testing

```ini
shell> cat hosts
host_1

[nfs]
host_2

[docker]
host_3
```

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/nfs.yml 
extra: [nfs]
```

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/docker.yml 
extra: [docker]
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    base: [sshd, vector]
    # extra: []
    mon: "{{ base + extra|d([]) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: mon|to_yaml
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yml

ok: [host_1] => 
  mon: [sshd, vector]

ok: [host_2] => 
  mon: [sshd, vector, nfs]

ok: [host_3] => 
  mon: [sshd, vector, docker]
```

Comment: It's what I do, but if host_2 is also in docker group, I don't have all the results (sshd, vector, nfs, docker).

Here the results :


    `↳  host_1 | SUCCESS | 24ms`
    `{`
     `- mon|to_yaml: [sshd, vector]`
   `}`
   `↳  host_2 | SUCCESS | 34ms`
    `{`
      `- mon|to_yaml: [sshd, vector, nfs]`    
   `}`
   `↳  host_3 | SUCCESS | 36ms`
    `{`
     `- mon|to_yaml: [sshd, vector, docker]`


Here the hosts file with this playbook : 

   `host_1`
   `[nfs]`
    `host_2`

    `[docker]`
    `host_2`
    `host_3`